# prevent natbib from including all (uncited) references in the pdf file

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

I have a simple tex doc in `article` class which relies on `\usepackage{natbib}`, with the following bibliography,

```
    \vfil\eject
    \raggedright
    %\vspace{-0.15in}
    \bibliographystyle{unsrt}
    \bibliography{../../libtex/all}
```

This somehow includes **all 1000s of references** in the `all.bib`. That is not what I want. I need only the references cited to appear at the end. How can this be resolved? What is causing this behavior? clash with another package? Am I missing a setting/command in the tex file? Is there a better package than `natbib` to achieve the goal?

This issue with natbib is driving me crazy and has wasted almost a day of my life. I appreciate your help as I am approaching a deadline fast.

Comment: you probably have a \nocite{*} somewhere.

Comment: You are my hero. One of the included files had a `nocite*` in an obscure location. Please write it in response to accept it as the correct answer.